# Display a popup (JDialog) when someone clicks on save button

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, popup, jdialog

How to display a popup (`JDialog`) when someone clicks on save button?

Basically I'm working on a Database Management Java App using Netbeans.
I have finished the design and have also linked the java program to MySQL server.
I have used two buttons - RESET and SAVE

I would like to popup a window which says "Data has been saved" and which has an "OK" button.

Could anyone give me an idea/ an example on how this can be done?

Answer (score 4):

Just construct a [`JOptionPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) dialog.

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(myFrame,
                "Data has been saved.");
```

You will find [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) how to make these dialogs.